# Can a subquery be used with the VALUES keyword?

Tags: sql, subquery, oracle-xe, dml

I was under the impression that it could not, but then I ran across these 2 examples (using Oracle XE and SQL Developer):

**Example 1** - executes without error

```
insert into regions (region_id, region_name)
values ((select max(region_id)+1 from regions), 'Great Britain');
```

**Example 2** - returns error (shown below)

```
insert into regions (region_id, region_name)
values (select region_id, region_name from regions);
```

Error:

```
Error starting at line 1 in command:
insert into regions (region_id, region_name)
values (select region_id, region_name from regions)
Error at Command Line:2 Column:9
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00936: missing expression
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

So, it appears that there is more to it. Can anyone provide an explanation of under what conditions it is/isn't ok to include subqueries with the `VALUES` keyword?

Comment: I have an Oracle book that says...A subquery can be used to select rows for insertion but not in a VALUES clause of an INSERT statement...which, that'd be cool if it was true. But, as you pointed out with example 1, it's not true. You can use subqeuries in the values clause, like you showed above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to insert subqueries in parentheses.  The opening paren for `values` doesn't count.  It is the start of a list, not a subquery.  You can include subqueries in the `VALUES` clause when they return one row and one column.

Instead, though, you can use this syntax:

```
insert into regions (region_id, region_name)
    select max(region_id) + 1, 'Great Britain'
    from regions;
```

Better yet would be to assign a sequence to the `region_id` (identity or auto-increment column in other databases) so it is assigned automatically.  Then you would just do:

```
insert into regions (region_name)
    select 'Great Britain'
    from dual;
```

Comment: Got it - so, only scalar subqueries are allowed in the `VALUES` clause?

Comment: @JeffLevine . . . Yes, that is a good way of saying it.  I avoid the `VALUES` clause simply because `insert . . . select` does everything it does, and a whole lot more.